# Sort a list of nested dictionaries by values without knowing its keys [Python]

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, nested

As the title says I'm trying to sort a list of nested dictionaries without knowing its keys.
If possible I'd like to use one of the 2 following functions to solve my problem:

- [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)
- [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

I want it to be sorted by `occurrences` OR `tf-idf` (same shit)
I've currently tried both with lambdas but nothing worked.

Sample of my data:

```json
[
    {
        'batch': {
            'occurrences': 2,
            'in_docs': [0, 4],
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348
        }
    },
    {
        'set': {
            'occurrences': 2,
            'in_docs': [0],
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'idf': 1.6094379124341003,
            'tf-idf': 0.0062020728802855505
        }
    },
    {
        'connect': {
            'occurrences': 2,
            'in_docs': [0, 3],
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348
        }
    },
    {
        'login': {
            'occurrences': 2,
            'in_docs': [0, 4],
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348
        }
    },
    {
        'change': {
            'occurrences': 2,
            'in_docs': [0, 4],
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348
        }
    }
]
```

If you have any ideas it would be great !
Thanks.

Comment: You have one layer of useless dictionnaries in your list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `lambda` to `sorted` function as key:

```py
sorted(data, key= lambda x: x[[*x.keys()][0]]['tf-idf'])  #data is your list
```

*Use `occurrence` instead, inplace of `tf-idf` if you want to sort on the basis of value of `occurrence` inside the dictionary, but since you have the same value for `occurrence` inside each dictionary items, sorting on the basis of `occurrence` for the sample data may not make any differene.*

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[{'batch': {'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'in_docs': [0, 4],
            'occurrences': 2,
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348}},
 {'connect': {'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
              'in_docs': [0, 3],
              'occurrences': 2,
              'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
              'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348}},
 {'login': {'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
            'in_docs': [0, 4],
            'occurrences': 2,
            'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
            'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348}},
 {'change': {'idf': 0.9162907318741551,
             'in_docs': [0, 4],
             'occurrences': 2,
             'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
             'tf-idf': 0.0035309854792838348}},
 {'set': {'idf': 1.6094379124341003,
          'in_docs': [0],
          'occurrences': 2,
          'tf': 0.0038535645472061657,
          'tf-idf': 0.0062020728802855505}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by -
values = dictionary_name.values()
values.sort()
print(values)
The value that will be printed will be sorted